# Graphical application.config editor?

Tags: c#, configuration

I am wondering if .net has some sort of inbuilt gui for editing application.config files.

From googling around it seems that they exist but are designed to be run from visual studio.

What I want to do is to allow admins of the software I am writing to be able to customise the application config from within the software at a customers site.

Could someone advise me if this is possible?

At the minute I thinking I will have to wite my own code to parse the config files to generate the Gui.

Comment: Don't know about anything "builtin", but you could roll your own without too much work, couldn't you? Here is a link that might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6160/Application-Configuration-Editor-using-the-Propert

Comment: Yeh i assumed I was going to roll my own, but just thought I would check that there wasnt something already out there before I put effort into it :D Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create your own form whcih takes application.config values from user and update that in the application.config